# UILongPressGestureRecognizer not working after archiving application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, uilongpressgesturerecogni

When testing in iPad, I can successfully call the method attached to `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` in UILabel.

After I have archived the application for Enterprise deployment, UILongPressGestureRecognizer does not work anymore.

I have already added the following codes aside from manually ticking `User Interaction Enabled:`

In .h file:

```
@interface BGMSetMenuViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

In .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    itemPriceLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    itemNameLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressSetMenuPrice:)];
    longPress.delegate = self;
    [itemPriceLabel addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
}

#pragma mark - UILongPressGestureRecognizerDelegate

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
  return YES;
}

- (void)longPressSetMenuPrice:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
  if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    BGMPasscodeViewController *passcodeVC = [[BGMPasscodeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BGMPasscodeViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    [passcodeVC setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];
    [self presentViewController:passcodeVC animated:YES completion:nil];

  }
}
```

Anybody here who have the same experience?

Please note that this was working in Xcode 7 and iOS 9.

Now, I'm using Xcode 8 and testing in iOS 10.0.2 and it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Post some code of UILongPressGestureRecognizer with the question.

Comment: @JamshedAlam, I have added the some codes and explanation.

Comment: Did you set longPress.delegate = self?

Comment: @user3182143, yes I also have it and I have UIGestureRecognizerDelegate as well.

Comment: Without seeing other code,it is not possible to give solution.

Comment: @user3182143, wait a moment. I'll edit my question :)

Comment: Did you put break point inside the ongPressSetMenuPrice method and did you check  whether it is calling or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126503/discussion-between-julie-and-user3182143).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:set YES to label userIntractionEnabled also in storyboard

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
labelTouch.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self labelLongPressed:labelTouch];}


- (void)labelLongPressed:(UILabel *)label{
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 2; //seconds
longPress.delegate = self;
[label addGestureRecognizer:longPress];}

-(void) handleLongPress : (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
  UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender.view;
   NSLog(@"longpress");}
```